# How do I make Tmux display time in a different time zone?

Tags: datetime, tmux

Hitting `<tmuxPrefix> + t` displays the time on my server but I want it to display the time in my current timezone rather than the server's timezone.

I run into the same issue when I want to display the time in the status bar in my current timezone.

I was able to partially fix it by using the following command:

```
set -g status-right '#(TZ="Asia/Kolkata" date )'
```

But when I use modifiers like `%H`, `%M`, `%S` in the status, as below, it ends up showing the time in the server's time zone.

```
set -g status-left '%H:%M:%S'
```

I have updated my `.bashrc` config with `TZ="Asia/Kolkata"`. This gives me time in the right timezone when I run the `time` command in bash but it doesn't seem to use the variable in a Tmux session.

Can anyone please let me know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 20):

For the second part of your question, you can use:

```
set -g status-right '#(TZ="Asia/Kolkata" date +%%H:%%M:%%S)'
```

Comment: What if I'm using `set -g status-right "%a %b %d %R"`?

Comment: The important part here is the double `%`.  I had a similar issue, I work with people across multiple timezones, and if they were just one ahead or one behind it would be easy and not an issue, but I wanted to display multiple timezones to keep track of that.  I had had to add the double % ( `%%H:%%M` ) in order for it display correctly.  Example...`set-option -ag status-right '#[bg=white]#(TZ="America/Los_Angeles" date +" %%H:%%M ")#[bg=#4B92DB]#(TZ="America/Chicago" date +" %%H:%%M ")#[bg=yellow]#(TZ="Europe/Bucharest" date +" %%H:%%M ")'  `

Answer (score 7):

What I do is set the timezone for my user. 
It works beyond tmux, it will translate anything that displays dates and times, like the output of 'ls' for example.

Edit your ~/.profile and set the TZ variable, for example:

```
export TZ=/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific
```

You can also make ssh send your current timezone automatically. Make sure you have TZ in the ~/.profile of your laptop then instruct ssh to send it by adding this to ~/.ssh/config

```
SendEnv TZ
```

The remote server has to be configured to accept it, if it doesn't work make sure it has this in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_* TZ
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have white space in the datetime format you can use:

```
set -g status-right '#(TZ="Asia/Kolkata" date +"%%h %%d %%H:%%M")'
```